# What are the easier to qualify home loans in Canada?

Tags: canada, mortgage, credit-history

I have only 6 unpaid things on my credit report. The small things add up to only $17XX.00 but the oldest thing, an unpaid credit card from 5 or 6 years ago, has nearly doubled to $11,000 due to interest and fees.

My three credit scores are 576, 599, 576. After paying off the $17XX.00 I want to get a loan to buy a single family home or move-in ready multi-family home in Canada. I live in the US at the moment, so I think my credit won't be a problem in another country, but with no credit history at all and a lower than usual income I'll still need a non-traditional mortgage.

Once my credit report listed debt has been completely paid off, except for the ancient credit card, what are my best options for securing a mortgage? I need something specifically for people with low incomes. Can you name different loans that are best for this situation?

Comment: 6 unpaid, meaning active accounts, payments current, or 6 past due?

Comment: I called that mortgage company and they say that you can't use income from outside of Canada. It doesn't matter what it is but you can't use it even if it's passive income. So For the Canadian company you listed, I'd have to put down a 35% down payment and deposit 1 full year of mortgage payments into a Canadian bank. They say that's the only way. Are there other options in Canada?

Answer (score 4):

Your credit score is really bad, and it's highly unlikely anyone will be willing to give you a mortgage, especially if you still have bad debt showing up on your credit report.

What would help? Well, clearing off any bad debt would be a good place to start. Ideally, you want to get your credit rating up above 680, though that may be optimistic here. Note, though, that bad debt falls off your credit report after a while. Exactly how long depends on your province. Note that making partial payment, or even just acknowledging the debt, will reset the 'timer', however. I mention this, though, because you mention some of your debt is from 5 or 6 years ago. It may be just about to fall off. It would also help if you can show that your credit is so bad because of mistakes from a number of years ago, but you've been making payments and staying on top of all debts for the past few years, if that's the case.

Also, it would help if you had a reasonable downpayment. 20% minimum, but you'll be a lower credit risk if you are able to put down 50 - 75%. You could also consider having someone with good credit co-sign the mortgage. Note that most people will not be willing to do this, as they take on substantial financial risk.

All that said, there are some institutions which specialise in dealing with no credit or bad credit customers. You pay more fees and will pay a vastly higher interest rate, but this may be a good option for you. Check out mortgage brokers specialising in high-risk clients.

You can also consider a rent-to-own, but almost all the advice I've ever seen say to avoid these if you can. One late payment and you may lose all the equity you think you've been building up.

Note that things may be different if you are moving from the U.S. to Canada, and have no credit history in Canada. In that case, you may have no credit rather than bad credit. Most banks still won't offer you a mortgage in this case, but some lenders do target recent immigrants.

Don't rule out renting. For many people, regardless of their credit rating, renting is a better option. The monthly payments may be lower, you don't need a downpayment, you don't have to pay realtor and legal fees (and pay again if you need to move).

A couple of sites provide more information on how your credit rating affects your possibility of getting a mortgage, and how to get mortgages with bad credit: http://mortgages.ca/credit-score-needed-mortgage-canada/ and http://mortgages.ca/mortgage-solutions/new-to-canada-financing/, along with  http://www.ratehub.ca/mortgage-blog/2013/11/how-to-get-a-mortgage-with-bad-credit/